How to install wheel file dependency with extras on Databricks?
One of my workflows has a python wheel file dependency. However that wheel file also has extra dependencies that need to be installed. How can I do that on databricks?
I tried using a init script but it doesn't work. I want to do something analogous to:
pip install "path/to/wheel/file/mywheel.whl[extras]"

How to achieve this in a Databricks workflow? The entry point to the task is a python function defined in the wheel file.

Can you please edit this with specific about what "doesn't work" means? Include any relevant logs or error messages in plaintext, for example.

Does this answer your question? How to pip install with wheel specifying extras?

@JamesLamb I want to be able to do it in a databricks workflow. How do I do that? I can't run a command because the workflow task runs a python function. But to run the function these extra dependency is required. The other option I have is to rebuild the wheel file with the extra dependency changed to a normal one which I am hesitant to do as this dependency is only required in this particular use case.

Could you please edit your question to clarify exactly what you tried and what you mean by "doesn't work"? If "Databricks workflows" refers to some specific feature of that service, include a link to docs for that as well... I assumed from your initial post that that was just generic language for "I am using Databricks".
